# scite: colored text

Tags: formatting, scite

I want to have colored text in scite to help make simple ascii maps/graphics.
I have created a neew properties file called map.properties and imported it.

but what will be its content?
I want to be able to give a different color to each alphabet.
so "a" may come in green, "b" in red and so on.

This should only affect the files *.map.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The properties files work together with a parser written for a specific syntax.
So you have to specify both the properties file and the parser.
Sometimes a parser can be re-used.
The c, c++, c# and java syntaxes look very much the same and was therefore done under one parser.
There is no parser that parses all the letters of the alphabet seperately.
So you will need to make both a properties file and a parser.